# Is there a way to recreate an empty table structure from .CDX file alone, and possibly export it as SQL commands (CREATE TABLE)?

Tags: visual-foxpro, dbf

I was tasked to convert some old software that was made using Visual FoxPro, but I was given only some .CDX files. I have access to a VFP program (version 9) but I know nothing about dbf, cdx, etc. It seems that the program "imports" the .CDX all right, but I can't even find a way to see their content.

What I tried so far:

```
SET INDEX TO S:\mail.cdx
```

Then I tried:

```
ATAGINFO(B, S:\mail.cdx)
```

that I found here and there, but nothing.

It seems to me that the learning curve here is very steep, because even the terminology I found is totally different both from SQL and noSQL databases. Some help here would be highly appreciated.

Comment: As Ethan explained, cdx files only contain the index information and index values in it in a special 'compressed' way. You wouldn't get any table structure information from that. If you don't know VFP at an advanced level, even with tables and source codes, you wouldn't be doing things easily. My suggestion, forget the structures, code and do everything from scratch. You would lose less time. IMHO, that "conversion" is not an easy task for everybody.

Comment: @CetinBasoz the problem is, the company has saved valuable data in that format, so the important thing is to recover the data. I can rebuild another solution from scratch, but if I get both .dbf and c.dx, wouldn't it be possible to extract structure and data and convert it to a SQL format? I've seen there are some project to interface with dbf in python, for example; if that could work, I could manage the rest.

Comment: If you have all the data files, then yes you could get data into an SQL or NoSql database. I can't talk for python, I have been doing that for years with MS SQL server, postgreSQL, SQLite, MongoDb using C#, Go, VFP. I remember I have found something with python driver but I really do not work with python (it should be in one of my older messages). You are not just safe with DBF and CDX. There might be other files, typically FPT and probably DBC, DCT and DCX (and hope there is no columns that are set as system).

Comment: DBF files is the main database tables , if you just want to recover the data and you get the DBF files, then you can use the MS SQL Sever import Wizard  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2463/importing-dbf-files-into-sql-server/

Answer (score 2):

`.CDX` files only have the indices, so you won't find all the fields there; ideally, you should be given the `.DBF` files, and a `.DBC` file if it exists.

Even if you get those files, though, you'll still only have the fields and indices.  What you really need is the Foxpro source code for the software.